# iPhone restart after long time in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, service, restart

Dears,
I have an own app (not for App store) that executes some processes, after that it opens an other app which waits for N seconds and than the second-one re-opens the first one. This app is designed like a service, and all the time works.

```
T0 -> App 1 (executes processes)  
T1 -> App 1 opens App 2  
T2 -> App 2 WAITs & App 1 kills itself  
T3 -> App 2 opens App 1  
T4 -> T0
```

Now, everything works well, this workaround helps me to clean cache and variables.

**PROBLEM**
I'm running under iOS 9.3.2 iPhone 5 and the iPhone is all time active in foreground.
After exactly 4 hours, the iPhone restarts itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: how often does t0 -> t4 happen, and is it all completely automatic or does it take user input for this to happen?

Comment: Hi Fonix. No user input is needed, completely automatic. t0->t4 happens every two minutes.